# Unable to add RST reference from different file

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In the RST Documentation file, after making a :ref command, I am unable to generate a link to the targetted section.

This is the edited file:
https://github.com/rahulchhabra07/pcl/blob/master/doc/tutorials/content/narf_keypoint_extraction.rst

This is the target file: https://github.com/rahulchhabra07/pcl/edit/master/doc/tutorials/content/range_image_visualization.rst

Kindly let me know, how do I make sure the link works for the label.

Comment: When I click on the second link, I see a message that says "Sorry, you’re not able to edit this repository directly— you need to fork it and propose your changes from there instead."

Comment: @mzjn Yes, you will have to fork it to see the underlying code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the range image visualization file is not getting included in the project; it's not listed in index file. So when sphinx looks for the target label, it does not find it.  If you don't want the target in the toc, you can include it in it's own toc and hide it:

```
.. toctree::
  :hidden:

  filename
```